# Access default unity desktop only over VNC connection

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, unity

I installed Unity desktop on my cloud instance (18.04.1 x64)

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and the VNC Server

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

What would be the contents of `.vnc/xstartup` file to invoke Unity desktop on a connection. I know for Gnome, its something like this :

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
metacity &
gnome-settings-daemon &
gnome-panel &
```

But what about Unity? I only need it to be invoked over VNC connection, rest of the time GUI shouldn't be taking up resources. Possible?

Help would be appreciated.